# event call on checkbox after ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 category each with a dropdown which have some values with checkbox. When checkbox is checked ajax run and gives response.

The issue is Dropdown hide after ajax response but I want it to be visible after ajax response

For example

```
cat1 cat2 cat3
     --------------------------------------------
     -  option1             option3             -
     -                                          -
     -  option2             option4             -
     --------------------------------------------
```

Now when I hover on cat2 dropdown open up with options and when I click on option1(i.e on checkbox) ajax run after that dropdown is not visible it hides.

I want to make the dropdown visible after Ajax response.

I worked on this with an intermediate solution and now Iam stucked again. on checkbox click I had generated a unique Id for the "ul" tag that i want to show after ajax response.

Here is what I am doing for it:
 `var $tag = jQuery(ee1.target).parents(".common-class").prop("id");` 
This code gives me unique Id on checkbox click.
 I want to add css on it like : 
`$tag =jQuery(ee1.target).parents(".common class").prop("id").css("display","block");`
 But this is not working for me it starts refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a synchronous ajax call and then make the box visible..

This is how synchronous calls are made

```
var remote = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: remote_url,
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

Comment: Hello Danyal sorry for late reply. I worked on this with an intermediate solution and now Iam stucked again. on checkbox click I had generated a unique Id for the ul tag that i want to show after ajax response.